# Importing existing .gpkg files to create new Geopackage layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, mac, geopackage

I'm a new QGIS user running 3.14.0 on a Mac with Mojave 10.14.6. While following along with this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCnNWyl9qSE), I reached around the 22 minute mark and encountered an issue.

When attempting to create a "New GeoPackage Layer" by importing an existing .gpkg file I've already created, I click "..." next to Database expecting to be able to browse my computer and import this file. However, while I can see the file I want it is grayed out/not able to be selected. The window that pops up says "Save As..."; it seems like my only option is to create and save a brand new GeoPackage layer rather than create a new one using the existing .gpkg file like the tutorial does. What I need to be able to do is select "MyFirstData.gpkg"  (image below), but it won't let me.

Especially since I'm so new to QGIS, I feel clueless about how to fix this problem and I can't continue the tutorial unless I can manage to successfully import and existing .gpkg file.

Why does my system work differently than the one in the tutorial and why can I only "Save As" rather than upload existing files?

[image]

Comment: I'm not a mac user anymore hence only a comment, but I'd guess you would be able to just drag'n'drop the file from finder into QGIS to import.

Comment: I'm not a Mac user so a can't really advise but you could try connecting your existing gpkg first to see if this solve the problem (open the DB manager then right click on GeoPackage on the provider list and choose new connection). It should work without this steep but who know...). Just a small vocabulary precision : you are not trying to import an existing geopackge but to create/save a layer in an existing geopackge (as geopackage could be understand as container for geographic data).

Answer (score 4):

You could just try to type the same name and extension if it won't let you select it.
Or right click on the geopackage in the QGIS file browser window and add a new layer. Available under Layer>Data Source Manager>Browser.
[image]